# Mingw64 Installation added an Pyhton Version! How can I remove the mingw64 Python and keep mine?

Tags: python, windows-10, setuptools, pythonpath, ming

I have Python 3.8.10 64bit(win10) installed. I'm using it with VSC. Also for c/c++ I have installed mingw64. Mingw64 installs a python version to, dont know why and for what, but it is already making problems. Because the mingw64 installation is a systemwide installation and the Path is a Systemvariable, everytime  I try to run something from the console, the mingw64 python installation will be used. So my python installation is a local, user wide installation. So the systemwide Installation will be prefered everytime, except i specify the path everytime.

The most annoying problem is

```
PS C:\src\python-ivi-master> python .\setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\src\python-ivi-master\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.test import test as TestCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

It cannot find the modules, as example setuptools. If I list the installed packages, the module is there.

```
Package           Version
----------------- -------
easy-scpi         0.1.2
modbus            3.2
numpy             1.22.3
pandas            1.4.1
pip               22.0.4
pymodbus          2.5.3
pyserial          3.5
python-dateutil   2.8.2
python-ivi        0.14.9
pytz              2021.3
PyVISA            1.11.3
scpi              2.4.0
setuptools        60.10.0
six               1.16.0
typing_extensions 4.1.1
wheel             0.37.1
```

I dont want to go threw the whole installation process. How can I fix this? The most satisfying solution would be, to delete the mingw64 python enviroment.

Thanks a lot. I hope the post is understandable, it's my first post here. Love the Site and community, helped me with a lot of problems.

BR
**lost zorro**

I didnt try anything, because I dont want to ruin my installation and start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put the PATH of the python installation that you wish to use at the top of the list of the paths in the Environment Variables.

Currently the path of mingw64/bin is above you Python39 Path in the environment variables, so when when you run python in the terminal it reaches the mingw64 location first.